# Why does the simplexmethod 'break up' - unbounded, LP program, very basic problem

Tags: linear-programming

I've calculated a very, very basic LP problem:

with >= "greater or alike" and <= "smaller or alike"

> max x + 2y
>
> > 4x + 3y >= 12
> >
> > > x <= 4

With ORSTAT (LP program) this turned out to be "Unbounded", which I understand. However, as to why the simplexmethod terminates, the book says:

> because in the 3rd tableau there ain't no pivot in the Surpl1-column

I don't get it?! Why is this the reason...Why should there be a pivot in the S1-column?

As for the output:

[image: Iterations]

Comment: The "Rel. Cost"-line has to be "0" for X,Y, Surp.1 and Slack2 and RHS. The only negative coefficient of the "Rel. Cost"-line" is the the column of Surp.1. But you cannot choose a row, because $\frac{4}{-0.33}$ is negative and $\frac{4}{0.00} \not \in \mathbb R$ Thus you do not have an optimal solution.

Comment: Got it. @calculus, Thank you!